# Help me identify this insect

Tags: entomology, species-identification

Over the last week or so as warmer weather has arrived, I've noticed small insects crawling around in the bathroom. I'm located in western Europe. They are perhaps 1mm in length, quite difficult to see without a magnifying glass. I used a macro lens to capture these pictures. What might they be? Ticks? Aren't ticks larger? Why are there so many?

Note: these pictures are **heavily magnified** (they are on an old wooden door with cracking paint), and I've applied lighting auto correction. Actual size of each insect is 1mm or less.

[image: Macro lens on highest magnification]

[image: Lower magnification, group of insects]

[image: Sheet of toilet paper for reference]

[image: With natural lighting]

Comment: I can't tell if those have 6 legs and large antenna, or 8 legs and no antenna. If 8 legs, then I suspect some sort of mite.

Comment: At the moment, my guess is louse or first instar nymph cycle of a bed bug. Can you obtain better pictures?

Comment: It looks like 6 legs and large antenna to me.

Comment: @rozmarin Yeah, the last 2 images show it better.

Comment: Definitely a spp of mite. And definitely *not* a bed bug. Sick of people always suggesting that small unknown insects are bed bugs -_-. Need bus *do* have their own distinct appearance...

Answer (score 6):

After a long hunt it seems they are Dermanyssus gallinae. It appears I have a pigeon's nest somewhere near my building.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dermanyssus_gallinae

[image]

Comment: You should add the picture.